# Reversing heat transfer with respect to time

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, linear-pde, heat-equation

Fact: One can easily compute heat dispersion in a plane using the heat equation.

Question: Has any research been done on computing the process in the reverse time direction?

That is, given a heat map $\eta : \mathbb [0,1]^n \to \mathbb R$, can we find a $\nu : \mathbb [0,1]^n \to \mathbb R$ which heats over a 1-second period to satisfy $\int_{s \in [0,1]^n}|\nu^{\text{Heated for 1s}}(s) - \eta (s)| < \epsilon$ for small enough $\epsilon$. Say you can base $\epsilon$ on $|\eta^{\text{any # of derivatives}}| \le M$ and use $M$ as a variable, etc. Anything that makes the problem solvable or convenient to be solved and isn't trivial.

If you just think about an infinitesimal in the forward time direction, $dt$, it comes natural that no information ought to be lost in this process, in theory. I did a search but I was unable to find any research papers or times where people have tried to compute heat transfer, say in the plane, in the reverse *time* direction.

[image]

To make it very obvious as to what I'm trying to do, it's to essentially reverse this arrow here ^. Thank you. Note that my plot is not showing all the information that is available, but that is simply an artifact of not showing enough subdivisions of the underlying space.

Comment: this is called backward heat equation and it is well studied. It is a classical example of an ill posed problem.

Comment: But there is sometimes a sense in which it can be well-posed, so maybe this can be an area for people to look into solving special cases for. (Or rather that it has been solved for some special cases, is what I'm really interested in) as some special case might still be useful in some contexts.

Comment: @Kostya_I it may be ill posed in a technical sense, but you can still minimize loss with respect to a fourier expansion capped to N=5000, for example.. Even though the problem is ill-posed I still believe there could be something to it, if that makes sense.

Comment: For the heat equation on domains, you can "completely" understand the behavior of the backwards heat equation in terms of the spectrum of the Laplacian; maybe this is the point of the downvote. But in fact this problem is quite interesting (backward uniqueness is a classical topic related to unique continuation) and its generalizations are actively studied. I know Fanghua Lin has thought about it extensively, you can find some discussion here on related homogenization problems: https://dx.doi.org/10.4310/MAA.2003.v10.n2.a5